# Getting error Exceeded maximum allowed stream duration of 65 seconds - when using SingleUtterance as conversation

Tags: google-cloud-speech

How can i continue  conversation more than 65 seconds  when using Single Utterance=true.My current implementation works partially, some time get Exceeded 65 seconds error.

I'm using web sockets.
I create a Speech Client & initialize GSA in each session (when starting  Single Utterance session) & close Speech Client get .END_OF_SINGLE_UTTERANCE'

Answer (score 0):

Which method from the Speech API are you using? if you are using the "recognize" method you should take into account is is synchronous but limited to 60s.

You might want to use "longrunningrecognize" instead, as it can take more than 60s.